# New domain is both registered with and hosted at AWS Route 53 but resolution fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have registered the domain duhastdiewahl.org at Amazon AWS Route 53.
I do it step for step like this:

http://share.pho.to/AAUSM

1. Create Hosted Zone (NS/SOA-Record default)
2. Add A-Record to my elastic ip adress for my EC2-Instance

Unfortunately if i ping the adress the name can't be resolved and tools like http://mxtoolbox.com says that the nameservers couldn't be found.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?
Thank you for your support :)

Comment: Have you waited for a few hours for the DNS to propagate?

Comment: There is some issue check your NS records when I Whois the domain I get this records Name Server: NS-1406.AWSDNS-47.ORG
Name Server: NS-607.AWSDNS-11.NET
Name Server: NS-458.AWSDNS-57.COM
Name Server: NS-1886.AWSDNS-43.CO.UK

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your nameservers are configured incorrectly in Route 53 "Registered Domains" -- they don't match the servers assigned to you in "Hosted Zones."

Route 53 is two different services -- domain registration and DNS hosting -- and the settings between the two of them need to match.  One possible cause of a mismatch is deleting and recreating your hosted zone.  That wouldn't fix anything, but a lot of people seem to try it anyway.  When you do that, it assigns four new name servers do your domain for hosting -- but the registrar service doesn't learn about this, because there's not necessarily a connection between the two services.  You could register a domain on one AWS account, and host the DNS on another, if you wanted -- the two "sides" of Route 53 are essentially independent.

To fix:

In the Route 53 console, click Hosted Zones, click your domain, and make a note of the assigned 4 name servers.  Don't change anything here.

Click "Registered Domains."

Select your domain.

Choose "add/edit name servers."

Enter the correct values for the assigned Route 53 name servers, which you obtained from the Hosted Zones screen.

Comment: I ran into this as well. Thanks for the great instructions!

Comment: @lonewarrior556 as noted above, *one possible cause of a mismatch is deleting and recreating your hosted zone.*  That, and creating multiple hosted zones for the same domain (only one of which can be used at a time) and trying to use the wrong one are the only causes that comes to mind.  The system doesn't stop you, presumably because "Route 53 Hosted Zones" and "Route 53 Domains" (Registrar) are two services that are loosely coupled and not necessarily used together -- either service (DNS host, registrar) can be obtained from an alternate vendor, while using the remaining service from AWS.

Comment: it worked perfectly after making this fix. remember to allow some time after the updates. it takes time for changes to work.