# Route 53, cannot access any A address as DNS hasn't propagated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a route 53 zone and some record sets in it.  None of my A addresses have propagated across the internet, it's been over 5 hours.  I am not sure what's going on, can anyone please please help?

My issue is similar to this
[New domain is both registered with and hosted at AWS Route 53 but resolution fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533568/new-domain-is-both-registered-with-and-hosted-at-aws-route-53-but-resolution-fai/37534217#37534217) although my domain registrar is another provider where I have updated the NS values.  So when I go to https://mxtoolbox.com/ and resolve a record set which has a CName it gets resolved fine but anything with an A type doesn't get resolved.

Comment: When did you update the NS values? Those take usually 24-48 hours to propagate world wide.

Comment: Well over 6 hours ago.  They do say that but when I go to `https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/XXX.XXX.com` the only places where it hasn't propagated is NZ/AU which are the two countries I care most about

Comment: Weirder is that I can access the site from my local office machine which is in NZ but not from outside the network.  I have no idea what's special about my internal office network.

Comment: Honestly, wait one more day and check again. If you have your settings correct there should be no problems tomorrow. Your experience in/out of the office when hitting your domain could be due to DNS caches, and also what DNS providers are set (as they might be grabbing data from more updated Zones)

Comment: I guess I can but it's affecting our customers so I am a bit reluctant to just "wait one day" unfortunately.  Is there absolutely no other way?  Also there is no guarantee that this will work after 1 more day right?!

Comment: In a nut shell, yes. As you do not control the DNS propagation. You can try https://serverfault.com/a/615021/409726 and see where your propagation is.

Comment: I have no idea what the output means, I have added it as a Gist here (https://gist.github.com/ruskindantra/9a21fbaf2b8bed72d3af6e17a0060591), what is it telling me about the propagation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: website name censored - was disclosed during private chat via SO. I'll let @Ruskin decide if he wants to paste the website for people to investigate further.**

https://dnschecker.org/#A/XXX.XXX.com shows that it is almost worldwide. DNS changes for root NS takes usually 24-48 hours to reach everyone, worldwide.

From Seattle, WA:

```
dig +add +trace XXX.XXX.com                     

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> +add +trace XXX.XXX.com
;; global options: +cmd
.           5   IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           5   IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           5   IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           5   IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           5   IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           5   IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           5   IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           5   IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           5   IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           5   IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           5   IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           5   IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           5   IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           5   IN  RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20170504050000 20170421040000 14796 . <snip>
;; Received 525 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1) in 2 ms

com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            86400   IN  DS  30909 8 2 E2D3C916F6DEEAC73294E8268FB5885044A833FC5459588F4A9184CF C41A5766
com.            86400   IN  RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20170506170000 20170423160000 14796 . <snip>
;; Received 866 bytes from 198.97.190.53#53(h.root-servers.net) in 84 ms

XXX.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns-689.awsdns-22.net.
XXX.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns-436.awsdns-54.com.
XXX.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns-1707.awsdns-21.co.uk.
XXX.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns-1169.awsdns-18.org.
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - CK0Q1GIN43N1ARRC9OSM6QPQR81H5M9A NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20170427044835 20170420033835 27302 com. c/BSwOzn216Af6oPN7R6d2XpLCjeshDHpH/5NiUlCZmqqys0J/JZWzif 7BxbsKUgxML/47n8wwQUOE/ah4QnANvT6UasinS+1PponrcLQXjQI2s5 z4JmrXLieCYUQUuAiO/wf3ZFhdMV2/p3V4pYGF0mH0zQ8M0EcvmAWu7z 66w=
EABGLTFA42VFSQFT6MQ54U3GMAQ2OO4H.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - EABJP3CV31DMGS2MHVSFR6R5BGG3SG0N NS DS RRSIG
EABGLTFA42VFSQFT6MQ54U3GMAQ2OO4H.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20170429042916 20170422031916 27302 com. <snip>
;; Received 697 bytes from 192.52.178.30#53(k.gtld-servers.net) in 152 ms

XXX.XXX.com.        300 IN  A   <snip>
XXX.com.        86400   IN  NS  ns-1169.awsdns-18.org.
XXX.com.        86400   IN  NS  ns-1707.awsdns-21.co.uk.
XXX.com.        86400   IN  NS  ns-436.awsdns-54.com.
XXX.com.        86400   IN  NS  ns-689.awsdns-22.net.
;; Received 196 bytes from 205.251.198.171#53(ns-1707.awsdns-21.co.uk) in 19 ms
```

One DNS server that doesn't have it is Melbourne, Australia (Pacific Internet):

```
dig +add +trace XXX.XXX.com @secdns.pacific.net.au

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> +add +trace XXX.XXX.com @secdns.pacific.net.au
;; global options: +cmd
;; Received 28 bytes from 61.8.0.101#53(secdns.pacific.net.au) in 172 ms
```

---

Long story short: wait a day and check again, most likely everything will be good.