# My AWS s3 static website will not resolve to the Route 53 domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I'm having trouble with an AWS s3 static website. I can access the static website using the s3 bucket website endpoint `http://mydomainame.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`. I cannot access it using `mydomainname.com` . The s3 bucket name, `mydomainname.com`,  is the same as the domain name. I have an alias, A record, in Route53 setup with record name = `mydomainname.com` and the value = `s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` The region for the bucket is the same as the alias. The domain was created in Route 53.

The bucket permissions are publicly available. Executing curl against my domain returns curl: (6) Could not resolve host.

Comment: The nameservers were configured incorrectly.
See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533568/new-domain-is-both-registered-with-and-hosted-at-aws-route-53-but-resolution-fai?rq=1).